# How to check with checkbox ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

If I use NG-IF in the check box and have test.check = "Y" value, I want to check the check box when I search. Is this the case?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng -if=" test.check == 'Y' chekced"  value="{{test.roomNum}}" check-list="checkedModel.roomNum">{{assign.roomNum}}
```

Comment: Are you using angularJS (version 1.x) or Angular2+?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use `ngIf` in this case, you can use `[checked]`. Change your html to the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="test.check === 'Y'"
                       value="{{test.roomNum}}" 
                       check-list="checkedModel.roomNum">{{assign.roomNum}}
```